# Does KafkaJS auto-pause during rebalancing?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

Does KafkaJS automatically pause during rebalancing? It's not mentioned in the KafkaJS docs what's going to happen during a rebalance. Or how does KafkaJS handle rebalance?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It might be more productive to ask about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't poll during a rebalance, but it doesn't "pause network connectivity". It will try to rejoin the group, then continue polling when it does.